# How can I get a date after 10 days ? in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date

This code returns today's date:

```
  Dim next10days As Date = Date.Now
```

But how can I get the date for the 10th day from today?

Comment: Wasn't there a movie made about that? ;-) How To Get a Date in 10 Days...

Comment: ++ Came here to make the same comment. ;-)

Comment: I believe that would be more along the lines of:
Dim HowToLosAGuyIn10Dyas As Date = Date.Now.AddDays(10)

Answer (score 22):

```
Dim next10days As Date = Date.Now.AddDays(10)
```

Answer (score 7):

**1. If you were to simply return the value:**

```
//C#
return DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

//VB
Return Date.Now.AddDays(10)
```

**2. If you really just want a variable you can work with:**

```
//C#
var MyDate10DaysFromNow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

//VB
Dim MyDate10DaysFromNow as Date = Date.Now.AddDays(10)
```

Comment: I thought about adding the sample in perl too.

Answer (score 0):

[msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

```
    ' Calculate what day of the week is 10 days from this instant.
Dim today As System.DateTime
Dim answer As System.DateTime

today = System.DateTime.Now
answer = today.AddDays(10)

System.Console.WriteLine("{0:dddd}", answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim next10days As Date = Date.Now.AddDays(10)
```

Although, technically, it should be `Date.Today`, not `Date.Now`, because `Now` also includes the time and you only want a date.

Comment: wow three answes and 18 upvote in the time i wrote this! (ok, i was reading other questions, too)